# Data from mysql is not getting retrieved on every page refresh

Tags: php, mysql

Iam trying to fetch the random data from mysql database, but it only fetches the same row on page refresh

I tried to run the query to get the random single row data from mysql and display on the webpage using php, but it only retrieving only the same row every time
`$sql = "SELECT * FROM identity_explorer_demographics ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`

```
<?php



$link = mysqli_connect("host", "username", "password", "db_name");

if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


$sql = "SELECT * FROM identity_explorer_demographics ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";


if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th>email_md5</th>";
                echo "<th>age_group </th>";
                echo "<th>age</th>";
                echo "<th>income</th>";
                echo "<th>Income_group </th>";
                echo "<th>gender</th>";
            echo "</tr>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['email_md5'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['age_group'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['age'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['income'] . "</td>";
                 echo "<td>" . $row['Income_group'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['gender'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        // Free result set
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    } else{
        echo "No records matching your query were found.";
    }
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

I need the random row data to be displayed everytime the page is refreshed. Will really be helpful if anyone can suggest be the best solution.

Comment: There is some debate about how random `RAND()` is - try `ORDER BY RAND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()))`

Comment: Tried this, still the same issue

Comment: Hi @KabirUlAlthamash, your query is working fine (tested), idk why u always had the same result,
`SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`

Comment: that query really should work, the error could be hidden somewhere else: did you check if `$sql` really has the query you want to execute at that step? or maybe there are many equal rows in the database?

Answer (score 0):

> $sql = "SELECT * FROM identity_explorer_demographics ORDER BY RAND()
>   LIMIT 1";

Change the line to

$randomv=rand(min,max);

> $sql = "SELECT * FROM identity_explorer_demographics ORDER BY $randomv
>   LIMIT 1";

Here is my implementation in another case where I have to choose from a random id available - Yii 2 Framework

```
   $prodcutids= \app\models\TblProduct::find()->all();
    $targetproduct=  ArrayHelper::map($prodcutids, 'id','id');


    $productdetails= \app\models\TblProduct::findOne(['id'=>array_rand($targetproduct)]);

    $productseriesname= \app\models\TblSeries::findOne(['id'=>$productdetails['Serie']]);
```

Or if you have an id column

> $sql = "SELECT * FROM identity_explorer_demographics WHERE id=$randomv
>   LIMIT 1";

rand(min,max)
min specifies the lowest value that will be returned.
max specifies the highest value to be returned.

Comment: Selecting by where id = '$randomv' is not an good idea, since a row with some id may not be exist sometime

Comment: ok now can select all the id into a array and select a random variable from that

Answer (score 0):

You mix it with PHP

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `identity_explorer_demographics`';

//Perform query and parse result, E.G $sql = db::query($sql);

function getRandomRow($sql) {
   $random_row = count(0, count($sql));
   foreach($sql as $row => $result) {
      if ($row == $random_row) {
         return $row;
      }
   }
}
```